# CouchDB javascript version: Date issue

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm using couchdb as downloaded from http://couch.io/get on Mac OS X 10.6, and it does not handle `Date`s properly. For example, the following view (map only) gives emits `{}` for date objects:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(new Date(), null);
}
```

The same thing holds for variations on the date: `Date("2000-10-10")`, `Date("2000/10/10")`, and `Date("10/10/2000")` all produce `{}`.

My guess is that this has to do with my javascript version, since `Date`s work as I'd expect on my Linux machine. Still, when I run js from the command line, it has a completely different behavior for `Date`s. If this is a version issue, then how can I tell what version of javascript CouchDB is running, how can I change that, and what version should I be running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that for some reason the date's `toString()` doesn't get called, so it is getting `{}` as a generic representation of a javascript object.

Not sure of the result you were expecting, but you could use one of these:

```
emit( (new Date()).toString(), null ); // Tue Jan 04 2011 13:24:48 GMT-0600 (CST)

emit( (new Date()).getTime(), null ); // 1294169100617
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the issue. If I call (new Date("2010/01/04")).toString() (with slashes instead of hyphens) then it works correctly. Do you know how to change what version of js couch uses, and what the best/most-up-to-date/standard version is?

Comment: @Danny: Sorry, but I don't know what the version is. I'm not even sure which interpreter they use. I'd be surprised if it was easy to change versions around. I have limited experience with CouchDB though, and only briefly fired up CouchDBX to make sure this solution worked.